# Update enhanced rich text column on SharePoint via VBA

Tags: list, rich-text, vba

I am using a ADOBD Connection as shown in the code snippet below to update a SharePoint list via VBA. It does not work for the "Description" column.

I believe it does not work because this column is in enhanced rich text format and I need to convert the string to this format. But I do not how to convert the string.

Currently this column has no content after updating the list. It works fine for the column "Title".

How do I update a column on a sharepoint list that type is set to enhanced rich text format?

```
Public Sub UploadToSharePointList()

[...]

With Rec_Set
    .ActiveConnection = Conn
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic ' adOpenStatic,
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic ' adLockPessimistic
    .Source = Sql
    .Open

    .AddNew
        .Fields("Title").Value = "Test Title 2"
        .Fields("Description").Value = "Enhanced RTF Text here"
    .Update

End With
[...]

End Sub
```